# Exec master..xp_cmdshell 'Del...' is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to delete a excel file using **xp_cmdshell**, but is not working... I check the other questions of here but I can't solve my issue, I activated the advanced options of SQL SERVER to allow this sintax, but it show's me a error message like this:

```
No se encuentra C:\xampp\htdocs\Web_Seguimiento\Body\Upload\Files\Carga
No se encuentra C:\WINDOWS\system32\Masiva
NULL
```

My code:

```
---- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO

declare @sqlquery varchar(255)
declare @name varchar(255)

set @name = 'Carga Masiva Usuarios General.xlsx'
set @sqlquery= 'Del C:\xampp\htdocs\Web_Seguimiento\Body\Upload\Files\'+@name +'' 
exec master..xp_cmdshell @sqlquery
```

Can anybody tell me what I do wrong, or how can I solve this issue...???

Comment: The issue is most likely that your excel file has spaces in the name.  Try wrapping the path in `"` eg. `'DEL "C:\...\Files\'+@name+'"'`

Comment: I personally think it is a bad idea to delete files using sql.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting quotes around the file name, like this:

```
set @sqlquery= 'Del "C:\xampp\htdocs\Web_Seguimiento\Body\Upload\Files\'+@name +'"'
```